# Rails/Mongoid: Can an embedded (embedded_in) document have many documents (has_many)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have a user who embeds many email_accounts. At the same time I wish that the email_accounts can have many email_templates. Is this possible? My Rails app refuses to accept the relations when I try to incorporate it.

I wish to make queries like e.g.:

```
email_template = EmailTemplate.first
email_template.email_account = current_user.email_accounts.where(:_id => params[:email_account_id).first
```

Here are the relations:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  embeds_many :email_accounts, :inverse_of => :user
  has_many :email_templates, :inverse_of => :user
end

class EmailAccount
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :email_accounts
  has_many :email_templates :inverse_of => :email_account
end

class EmailTemplate
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user, :inverse_of => :email_templates
  belongs_to :email_account, :inverse_of => :email_templates
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try changing your associations a bit:

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :email_accounts
end

class EmailAccount
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :user
  embeds_many :email_templates :inverse_of => :email_account
end

class EmailTemplate
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :email_account, :inverse_of => :email_templates
end
```

--> A **User** has many **EmailAccounts** which embeds **EmailTemplates**.

Then you could do:

```
email_account = current_user.email_accounts.find(params[:email_account_id])
email_account.email_templates << EmailAccount.all.map(&:email_templates).flatten.first
```

**You can't access embedded documents this way:**

```
email_template = EmailTemplate.first
```

**You have to go through EmailAccount first:**

```
email_template = EmailAccount.all.map(&:email_templates).flatten.first
```

To answer your first questions, I think it is possible but surely not the right way to go here. : )

Hope it helps.